# Get single data from session array - CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, session

I want to get single value from the flashdata array in the view which is sent from the controller.

**controller:**

```
        $post=array(
            'author_id'=>$this->input->post('author'),
            'title'=>$this->input->post('post_title'),
            'subtitle'=>$this->input->post('post_subtitle'),          
            'post'=>$this->input->post('textarea1'), 
            'image'=>$this->upload->file_name,          
        );

        $this->session->set_flashdata('postdata',$post);
```

**view**

```
<?php var_dump($this->session->flashdata('postdata'))?>
```

The above gave me the following result.

array(5) { ["author_id"]=> string(1) "6" ["title"]=> string(3) "uyk" ["subtitle"]=> string(26) "Full-Stack Web Development" ["post"]=> string(1) "u" ["image"]=> string(0) "" }

How can I get only single value like title or subtitle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this `$this->session->userdata['postdata']['title']`